# Susceptibility in the paramagnetic Ising model

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, ising-model

In the Ising model (2D for simplicity), the magnetic susceptibility casts the form

$$
\chi = \beta\left(\langle M^2\rangle - \langle M\rangle^2\right)
$$

We know that the susceptibility peaks at the transition temperature between ferromagnetic and paramagnetic phase. However, we can see that in the paramagnetic phase,
$$
\langle M^2\rangle=\frac{1}{N}\sum_iM_i^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i (\pm1)^2=1
$$
$$
\langle M\rangle^2=\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_iM_i\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_i(\pm 1)\right)^2 = 0
$$
since $M_i = \pm 1$ and there is no net magnetisation in the paramagnetic phase. This means that the susceptibility becomes $\chi = \beta\sim1/T$, contradicting to the Curie-Weiss law. Where did I make my mistake?

Comment: Is $\beta=1/(k_BT)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: For $T>T_c$, we have $\chi \propto (T-T_c)^{-1}$. My focus is only in the paramagnetic phase ($T>T_c$), and gives $\chi=\beta$, clearly contradicts to the Curie-Weiss law.

Comment: But the condition 'net magnetisation vanishes' applies for all $T>T_c$. How can you explain this discrepancy between $\chi \propto (T-T_c)^{-1}$ and $\chi \propto T^{-1}$?

Comment: Did you check out Wikipedia? This seems very on-point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie%E2%80%93Weiss_law#Modification_of_Curie's_law_due_to_Weiss_field

Comment: I delete my comments, as there was something wrong in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the notation. Let us denote by $\sigma_i$, $i\in V\subset\mathbb{Z}^2$, the spins in your system.

The magnetization the takes the form
$$
M_V = \sum_{i\in V} \sigma_i.
$$
Therefore (note that the brackets denote expectation with respect to the Gibbs measure, not an average over spins as you seem to be doing),
$$
\langle M_V^2 \rangle
= \Bigl\langle\Bigl( \sum_{i\in V} \sigma_i \Bigr)^2\Bigr\rangle
= \Bigl\langle\sum_{i,j\in V} \sigma_i\sigma_j\Bigr\rangle
= \sum_{i,j\in V} \langle\sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\langle M_V\rangle^2
= \Bigl( \Bigl\langle\sum_{i\in V} \sigma_i \Bigr\rangle\Bigr)^2
= \Bigl( \sum_{i\in V} \langle\sigma_i\rangle \Bigr)^2
= \sum_{i,j \in V} \langle\sigma_i\rangle\langle\sigma_j\rangle.
$$
Its variance is thus given by
$$
\operatorname{Var}(M_V) = \langle M_V^2 \rangle - \langle M_V \rangle^2
= \sum_{i,j\in V} \bigl( \langle\sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle - \langle\sigma_i\rangle\langle\sigma_j\rangle \bigr).
$$
In the thermodynamic limit, using translation invariance, the susceptibility can then be written as
$$
\chi = \lim_{V\to\mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{\beta}{|V|}\operatorname{Var}(M_V) = \beta \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^2} \bigl( \langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle - \langle\sigma_0\rangle\langle\sigma_i\rangle \bigr).
$$
Concerning your computations, note that, when $i\neq 0$, $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle\neq 1$ except at $T=0$, while $\langle\sigma_0\rangle=\langle\sigma_i\rangle = 0$ if $T>T_{\rm c}$.

In fact, the truncated 2-point function $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle - \langle\sigma_0\rangle\langle\sigma_i\rangle$ decays exponentially fast in $\|i\|$ at all $T\neq T_{\rm c}$ (in pure phases), but the decay becomes a non-summable power law at $T_{\rm c}$, which is the cause of the divergence of the susceptibility $\chi$.

Comment: How do we use this fact that the variant decays exponentially to derive the Curie-Weiss law?

Comment: You don't. The Curie-Weiss law only holds in the mean-field approximation, or above 4 dimensions. You can see the list of critical exponents of the Ising model [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_critical_exponents). The relevant one is $\gamma$.

Comment: If your more general question is "how do you obtain the critical behavior of the susceptibility?", then the answer is that this is hard. When $d=2$, you can make explicit computations to obtain the exact critical exponent. When $d=3$, you can obtain a good estimate of the critical exponent using, for instance, [conformal bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_bootstrap). The mean-field behavior above $4$ dimension can be rigorously derived, but this is not trivial either.

Comment: Of course, the derivation of the Curie-Weiss law *in the mean-field approximation* is easy.